# Exception when using C# wrapper with C API from Java application

Tags: java, c++, api, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to use C# code from a C API.  The C API is actually available from a Java application.

I have created a C++/CLI wrapper to call a simple C# function and have verified it works using a simple C++ console application.  I have also written C++ dll that works successfully with the C API published with the Java program.  Although when I try to use this same program to call the C++/CLI wrapper the host Java program exits immediatley without any errors.  I then tried instantiating the C++/CLI object and calling a member function within a try/catch block but it still exits immediately.  Here is my code:

```
try
{
CutLoggerGraphWrapper obj;
obj.SetRdoc(1.234);
}
catch (exception & e)
{
    AllocConsole();
    freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
    cout << e.what() << endl;
    FreeConsole();
}
```

When I attach a debug session in Visual Studio to the Java application (javaw.exe) it faults on the "CutLoggerGraphWrapper obj" line.

I have tried placing my dlls in several locations including in the same folder as the Java application dlls and then in a folder that is listed in the PATH environment variable.  I was thinking that it may not be loading the wrapper or C# dlls.  This didn't change anything.  I have not been able to make sense of what the problem may be from Visual Studio's output.  Here is the message from the output window.  Any suggestions?

```
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\cgtech70\windows64\jre\bin\javaw.exe'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nvinitx.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\cgtech70\windows64\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\cgtech70\windows64\jre\bin\hpi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\psapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\cgtech70\windows64\jre\bin\verify.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\cgtech70\windows64\jre\bin\java.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\cgtech70\windows64\jre\bin\zip.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\cgtech70\windows64\jre\bin\awt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winspool.drv'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\cgtech70\windows64\jre\bin\fontmanager.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\cgtech70\windows64\jre\bin\net.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\cgtech70\windows64\jre\bin\nio.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\cgtech70\windows64\jre\bin\jpeg.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\DisplayFusion\Hooks\AppHookx64_678D2E40-CE87-49FD-B8A9-B7BDE75F14AB.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_a4d6a923711520a9\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\cgtech70\windows64\vericut\CGTech.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wsock32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_88e41e092fab0294\msvcr80.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avifil32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvfw32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\glu32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ddraw.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dciman32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\cgtech70\windows64\jre\bin\jawt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\netapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\netutils.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\srvcli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wkscli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WSHTCPIP.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nlaapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\NapiNSP.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\pnrpnsp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winnsi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\FWPUCLNT.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\netbios.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\cgtech70\windows64\jre\bin\dcpr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x1688 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
First-chance exception at 0x0000000002C380E0 in javaw.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000028.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Dev\CutLogger\Build\Release\OptiAPI.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\cgtech70\windows64\vericut\CutLoggerWrapper.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mscoree.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\cgtech70\windows64\vericut\opapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp110.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr110.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr110_clr0400.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD96A49D (KernelBase.dll) in javaw.exe: 0x04242420 (parameters: 0x0000000031415927, 0x000007FEE7E60000, 0x000000000C3FDD40).
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\mscorlib\9da5bb33cd1c34b7851c088f0cf749cc\mscorlib.ni.dll'. 
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\cgtech70\windows64\vericut\CutLoggerWrapper.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\cgtech70\windows64\vericut\CutLoggerWrapper.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\cgtech70\windows64\vericut\CutLoggerWrapper.dll'
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System\e3305bdbd03ef919051aa7f2783ac32a\System.ni.dll'. 
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD96A49D in javaw.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x000000000C3FA640.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD96A49D in javaw.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD96A49D in javaw.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x000000000C3FA640.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD96A49D in javaw.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD96A49D in javaw.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x000000000C3FA640.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD96A49D (KernelBase.dll) in javaw.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0xFFFFFFFF80070002, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x000007FEE7E60000).
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD96A49D in javaw.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD96A49D (KernelBase.dll) in javaw.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0xFFFFFFFF80070002, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x000007FEE7E60000).
First-chance exception at 0x00000000083170A1 (jvm.dll) in javaw.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000E0000000.
First-chance exception at 0x00000000083170A1 (jvm.dll) in javaw.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000E0000000.
The thread 0x17ac has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1238 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xf7c has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x9c0 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1080 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x6c0 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xadc has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xcb0 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1704 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x178c has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1544 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1254 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xf0 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x16bc has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x510 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xc44 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x44c has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x15c8 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1154 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x7fc has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xd8c has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xee4 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x165c has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xaa8 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x9c4 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x15b0 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x16fc has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x141c has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xec0 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x13d0 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x17e8 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0xd44 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1630 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1204 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x7f8 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x14ac has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1340 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x428 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x5ec has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The program '[4796] javaw.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problems, it turned out to be the location of the C++/CLI wrapper and C# dlls.  I had to locate the dll's in the (appdirectory)/jre/bin.  I came to this conclusion after seeing some microsoft dll's in the same directory.

Comment: "appdirectory" is the path to the JRE that is being used.  For Example: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\ `.  Put the DLL's in that `\jre\bin\ `.